# Java classpath on Windows with custom packages

Tags: java, classpath, package, javac

I have the following file structure for a Java project I've been working on:

classes/ X/ Y/ Z/

Inside X/ Y/ and Z/ are my .java file for different parts of the project. They are packaged together respectively. When I compile everything together, I send all of my .class files to the classes/ directory using this command:

```
javac -cp classes/jsoup-1.8.3.jar -d ./classes/ X/*.java Y/*.java Z/*.java
```

This compiles just fine (I had placed the JSoup JAR file in the classes directory prior to this). Inside Z/, there is a Main.java with an appropriately declared `public static void main(String[] args)`. This file, along with all others are compiled, and their .class files are all sent to the /classes directory.

Now, when I try to run Main.class using `java Main` from within the classes/X/ directory, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

So I figured I would try messing with the classpath. I went two directories up and tried this:

```
java -cp jsoup-1.8.3.jar;./X/;./Y/;./Z/ Z/Main
```

But then all I got were instructions on how to use java, followed by

```
bash: ./X/: Is a directory
bash: ./Y/: Is a directory
bash: ./Z/: Is a directory
```

p.s. I am using Git Bash in Windows, so that is why I got the bash error instead of a cmd or powershell error. I have also tried using colon as the delimiter instead of semicolon, but unless I was doing something *else* wrong, that also did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Lets suppose you have:

myDir
  X a.class b.class
     -- Y d.class
     -- Z MainClass.class

where X,Y and Z are directories.
Y and Z are subdirectories of X, X is a subdirecory of myDir.

Position yourself in > myDir and execute:

```
java -cp "your jars..." X.Y.MainClass
```